# Potential energy change in a cyclotron

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, acceleration

Every source I've referred to elaborates on the 'energy of the particle' in a cyclotron to have increased by the time it exits, as it's been accelerated multiple times by an electric field. It *is* the kinetic energy they're referring to, and not the electrical(and the only) potential energy of the particle, which decreases, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is the kinetic energy they're referring to, and not the electrical(and the only) potential energy of the particle, which decreases, right?

Special Relativity four vectors define the kinetics of particles with Lorentz covariant [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) .

[image: fourv]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

You ask:

> It is the kinetic energy they're referring to, and not the electrical(and the only) potential energy of the particle, which decreases, right?

the kinetic energy is $1/2mv^2$ where the v is the velocity size, momentum is **p**=m**v** where both **p** and v are vectors ,

With each turn the momentum of the particle increases and because of the invariant mass the energy has to increase also. The potential energy in the accelerating fields is irrelevant, it is transferred to the  (kinetic energy)/momentum of the particle  each cycle  in pulses,  the last kick at the time it exits. The potential energy in the cyclotron is kept/fed at a calculated synchronous  level by the electricity provided.

Particles coming out of the cyclotron have the energy and momentum described above. The potentials entering the Maxwell equations play no role in what is defined as the energy of the beam particles from the cyclotron. ( see this for [electromagnetic waves)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know relativity or any of that stuff. Can you explain it in simpler terms?

Comment: I have edited, but if you are serious about accelerators you should study special relativity

Comment: "The potential energy...is transferred to the (kinetic energy)/momentum of the particle each cycle in pulses, the last kick at the time it exits." So yes, it is indeed the kinetic energy that increases, and not the total mechanical energy, right? That's all I need to understand.

Comment: Please respond.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "total mechanical energy", unless you mean the addition of the kinetic energies of all the particles in the cyclotron beam.

Comment: The sum of kinetic and potential energies of a body is it's total mechanical energy.

Comment: This is for classical mechanics studies. There is no such thing when studying elementary partcles, one uses the lorenz rules, the total energy of a particle is the sum of its mass energy plus its kinetic energy given in the four vector. Anyway, when the particle is out of the cyclotron  in the final kick, there is no potential on it

Comment: Okay, so 'With each turn the momentum of the particle increases and because of the invariant mass the energy has to increase also. ' does imply that it's kinetic energy that changes, right?

Comment: yes,  mass energy is invariant and characterizes the uniquenes of the particle, electron,proton etc

Comment: Thanks, just that bit about the kinetic energy being the variable factor is what I needed for the answer(at least for my understanding, which doesn't extend to relativity).